# StopIteration: iteration not started Error when zipping a cursor using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy, pandas

I've run into a `StopIteration: iteration not started` error while trying to order a table using an update cursor.

Is this caused by zipping the cursor together? I've tried updating a different table that's identical to the one I ordered using a search cursor. The error persisted. There's not a lot of good information about this error so I've decided to write this question primarily as a reference for others who run into this problem.

Here's the code I'm running on a FileGeoDatabase for now

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(
    in_table = copy_fc,
    field_names = fields, where_clause = "",
    sql_clause = (None, "order by DATE")) as ordered_cursor:

    sorted = [row for row in ordered_cursor]

sorted_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    data = sorted, columns = fields)

print sorted_df.size

fc = r"U:\R\A\qt\3.14159\;)"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_table = fc, field_names = fields)\
    as cursor:

    for (row, item) in zip(
        cursor, building_sorted_df.itertuples(index = False)):
        row = item
        #Error happens on line below
        cursor.updateRow(row)

print "Finished"
```

Please note, this is not a duplicate because I'm storing my values in a pandas data frame instead of trying to do pairwise iteration, my cursors are written correctly, and I'm not writing to a table while I'm reading from it.

Comment: @BERA The line with `cursor.updateRow(row)` I've edited a comment in my code block in the question for clarity

Comment: @Bera totally forget about that question. I didn't accept or upvote the answer there because that just wasn't what I was looking for as an answer to that question. Let me try it here. Even if it does work though, I'd like an explanation as to why my stuff isn't working here. I think it's worth documenting at the very least.

Comment: @BERA I actually ended up going with a list approach in that case. For some reason it's not working here either. Pandas is commonly used in a lot of my other scripts. Using pandas here just helps keep things standard.

Comment: It does not overwrite, da.InsertCursor is inserting new records.

Comment: @Bera so you're saying just delete all the records and put them back in? Won't can't that mess up your data?

Comment: @BERA I tried it. It was missing something so I put that in and it worked. If that's the case then I can only really assume that the zip was the issue. What other background information do you want me to include in my questions?

Comment: If you want to create a pandas df you dont need to create a list first, you can do: `df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fields,sql_clause=(None,sql)), columns=fields)`

Comment: yeah, but that's less readable. You'd also still have to put that in a context manager.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you dont want to use the Sort tool. Since you are trying to overwrite each row with the UpdateCursor it would be better to store all values in a list, truncate the fc which will delete all rows, and then use the insertcursor to insert the stored values again:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\Default.gdb\AnglePoints_1'
datefield = 'Date'

fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if not f.name.upper().startswith(('OBJ','SH'))]
fields.append('SHAPE@')
sql = """ORDER BY {0}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, datefield))
all_records_sorted = [i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fields,sql_clause=(None,sql))]

arcpy.TruncateTable_management(in_table=fc)
icur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc,fields)
for record in all_records_sorted:
    icur.insertRow((record))
del icur
```

[image]

Comment: How would it be better? Can you explain why using an update cursor is an anti-pattern?

Comment: Lets say you leave some field out of your `fields` list. You will then keep those fields records unchanged and update other fields with sorted data and have a mix of sorted and unsorted data.

Comment: I see, can you put that in your answer?

Comment: `arcpy.DeleteRows_management` is much better than truncate is here because it works with versioned data as well as non-versioned data.

Answer (score 0):

To explain the actual error for anyone coming across this question:

In Python 2.7, unlike 3.x, `zip` does *not* return an iterator.  As soon as you call it on the cursor, it immediately builds a tuple and exhausts the cursor before even entering the `for` loop.  It's basically equivalent to trying to loop over the same cursor twice, it's just that `zip` is doing it the first time.

Using `izip` will allow this to work in 2.7 (`from itertools import izip`).